# Does a reflective diffraction grating change the polarization of the light?

Tags: polarization, diffraction

I know that the diffraction efficiency is different if the incident light has a linear polarization parallel or perpendicular to the grating grooves, but regardless of the efficiency, is the polarization of the diffracted light the same as the incident light?

Comment: As you noted, the amount diffracted into different orders depends on the polarization of the incident light. So it is quite possible that some diffraction spot will have a different polarization mix than another, and that ratio will vary with diffracted order.

Comment: Okay, I guess this happens when the incident beam is unpolarized. What about the case, where we have pure linear polarization, let's say oriented parallel to the grooves. Will I also measure the same polarization at one of the diffraction spots?